# Logging in in the second time

Tags: reactjs

I am building a log in, just practice, so the problem is when I click Log in with the correct info, the first time it dont do nothing, it logs in the second time only. I think the problem is that the data stores in the state for first and then It verifies and continue to the next page
.
When the info is wrong it gives the error message for the first time but when I log in it logs in only with the second try

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
class Index extends Component {
  state = {
    errorMessage: false,
    isValueCorrect: false,
    info: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    },
    login: {
      email: 'Email@gmail.com',
      password: '1234'
    }
  };

  updateInfo = e => {
    this.setState({
      info: { ...this.state.login, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    });
  };
  submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (
      this.state.info.email === this.state.login.email &&
      this.state.info.password === this.state.login.password
    ) {
      this.setState({ isValueCorrect: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text-center container mt-4" style={{ width: '50%' }}>
        <form className="px-4 py-3" onSubmit={this.submit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            {this.state.errorMessage === true ? (
              <p className="text-danger">The email or the password is wrong</p>
            ) : null}
            <label>Email: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Email@example.com"
              className="form-control"
              name="email"
              value={this.state.info.email}
              onChange={this.updateInfo}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Password"
              className="form-control"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.info.password}
              onChange={this.updateInfo}
            />
          </div>
          {this.state.isValueCorrect === true ? (
            <Link to="Profile">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mt-3">
                Log in
              </button>
            </Link>
          ) : (
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mt-3">
              Sign in
            </button>
          )}
          <div>
            <Link to="/register" className="badge badge-light p-2 m-2">
              Register
            </Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're indeed correct in your assessment that the first click only validates the data. You're displaying either a submit button or a link pretending to be a submit button based on the `isValueCorrect` state flag. That flag is only set once the form is submitted whereas it should be set when the values are correct. There are a few ways you could fix this. Choose one, not both.

#### 1. Set the flag when the values are correct.

```
updateInfo = e => {
  const info = { ...this.state.info, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
  this.setState({
    info,
    isValueCorrect: (
      info.email === this.state.login.email &&
      info.password === this.state.login.password
    )
  });
};
```

And only handle error in `submit`.

```
submit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!this.state.isValueCorrect) {
    this.setState({ errorMessage: true });
  }
};
```

#### 2. Use `Redirect` instead of `Link`

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Replace the conditional `{this.state.isValueCorrect === true ...` ternary with

```
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mt-3">
  Sign in
</button>
```

and add a conditional path to render.

```
render() {
  if (isValuesCorrect) return <Redirect to="Profile" />
  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

### Other mistakes

- `login` in state is never changed, so it should be a static constant of the class instead of a filed in state.
- updateInfo spreads `state.login` into `state.info`, when it should propably spread `state.info` instead.